# Создать контекст на RGBA используя OpenGL ES для корректного отображения прозрачности

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, png, opengles

*С OpenGL ES столкнулся впервые, поэтому возникают вопросы.*

Основной вопрос: как создать контекст на RGBA используя OpenGL ES для корректного отображения прозрачности в разных программах?

Пытаюсь разобраться в коде где есть проблема с корректным сохранением png картинки.

---

Ситуация следующая:

**При создании картинки с прозрачным фоном в приложении созданная картинка после сохранения в png отображается в некоторых просмотрщиках(на винде) с чёрным фоном, а в некоторых нормально.**

Прозрачность созданных изображений в paint.net отображается корректно там где созданные мной png отображаются с чёрным фоном.

---

*Грешу на то что где-то недочёт в сохранении изображения и возникает проблема с корректным сохранением альфа каналов (хотя могу и ошибаться).*

Про сохранение:

```
- (UIImage *)renderToImage {
uint w = (uint)self.frame.size.width;
uint h = (uint)self.frame.size.height;

NSInteger         myDataLength = w * h * 4;
GLubyte *         buffer = (GLubyte *)malloc((size_t) myDataLength);
GLubyte *         buffer2 = (GLubyte *)malloc((size_t) myDataLength);
__block UIImage * image;

runOnMainThread (^{
    glFlush();
    glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, _frameBuffer);
    glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, _renderBuffer);
    glReadPixels(0, 0, w, h, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);

    for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
        int count = w * 4;
        for (int x = 0; x < count; x++) {
            buffer2[(h - 1 - y) * w * 4 + x] = buffer[y * 4 * w + x];
        }
    }

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef bitmapContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(buffer2, w, h, 8, 4 * w, colorSpaceRef,
                                                       kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault);

    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef);
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmapContext);
    CGContextRelease(bitmapContext);


    free(buffer);
    free(buffer2);

    image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
});

return image;
```

}

```
- (NSData *)saveImgChanges {
DDLogError(@"%s -- NOT IMPLEMENTED", __FUNCTION__);

__block NSData * updatedImageData = nil;

runOnMainThread (^{
    @autoreleasepool {

        UIImage * originalImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[self modifiedAttachmentData]];

        CGRect imageRect = CGRectZero;
        imageRect.size = originalImage.size;

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageRect.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
        [originalImage drawInRect:imageRect];
        [originalImage release];

        PR_AttachPageInfo * pageInfo = [_attachPagesInfo lastObject];

        PR_DrawView * drawView = nil;
        for (PR_DrawView * dv in _drawViews) {
            if (dv.tag == [self indexOfPageView:pageInfo.topLevelView]) {
                drawView = dv;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (drawView != nil && drawView.hasContent) {
            UIImage * image = [drawView renderToImage];
            [image drawInRect:imageRect];
        }

        UIImage * newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        updatedImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(newImage);
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }
});

return updatedImageData;
```

}

Будте добры, подскажите где может таиться недочёт?

Из-за чего могут возникнуть подобные проблемы?

Могли ли они возникнуть из-за косяка при создании этого изображения?

Каким образом можно создать контекст на RGBA?

Comment: Так все же, уточните вопрос, он про OpenGL или про просмотр PNG в разных программах или как создать контекст на RGBA?

Comment: Он про то как создать контекст на RGBA используя OpenGL ES для корректного отображения прозрачности в разных программах.

Comment: Это 2 разных несвязанных проблемы.

Comment: Подскажите в таком случае - в чём может крыться проблема с некорректностью отображения прозрачности?

Comment: Прозрачность созданных изображений в paint.net отображается корректно там где созданные мной png отображаются с чёрным фоном.

Comment: Дело в библиотеке которой вы сохраняете PNG.

Comment: А можно поподробнее?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось - проблема была с просмотрщиком.

Проблема решена.

В коде с использованием OpenGL ES проблем нет.

Comment: Ну так пометьте свой ответ как правильный.

Answer (score 1):

1. Проверяем исходные RGBA данные, сохраняем в виде AAA и проверяем что альфа правильная.
2. Если исходные данные верны, то дело в библиотеке которой вы сохраняете PNG. Видно она использует формат совместимый не со всеми просмотрщиками (у меня так было при использовании ImageCatalyst, некоторые png получались с разными фонами в разных программах).

Копайте в сторону настроек сохранения или бругой библиотеки.